# Hive- query output to file csv/excel

Tags: hive, directory, export, output, hue

I am trying to output the results of Hive to a File (preferably excel) I tried below methods and non of them work as explained in most posts. I wonder because I use Hue environment. I am new to Hue and hive, any help would be appreciated

```
insert overwrite  directory 'C:/Users/Microsoft/Windows/Data Assets' row format delimited fields terminated by '\n' stored as textfile select * from final_table limit 100;
```

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'C:/Users/Microsoft/Windows/Data Assets'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from final_table limit 100;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running the same query in my setup, it works fine.

In your case , it might be an issue with 'C:/Users/Microsoft/Windows/Data Assets' folder permission.

Try writing to different folder(User's Home folder).

> **Query:**
>   INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/fsimage' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE SELECT * FROM stream_data_partitioned limit 100;

**Output Attached** 
[image: Hive CLI output]

**Destination folder**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mahesh, If i run it on CMD it runs fine. however, on Hue it doest work. I am trying to do is to run it on Hue platform so I can cretae workflow and run schedule jobs to create the file. I am seeking is how I can run in in Hue